# Cocoapods fails to install by manual installation

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I am stuck at this error. I am trying to install again and again but still it gives same error. please help me to resolve this issue.

```
cd ~/.cocoapods/repos
Jawaids-Mac:repos jawaidahmed$ git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master
Cloning into 'master'...
remote: Counting objects: 916492, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (13641/13641), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 56 SSLRead() return error -98063.00 KiB/s   
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

Comment: Either your internet connection is interrupted during the clone or may be it is timed out.

Comment: Thanks dear Zeeshan, But I am trying again and again it gives same error

Comment: I ahev tried on 4G connection but it same error @MuhammadZeeshan

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried this but i think it will work.
Work around could be:

- Open your browser Goto [Cocoapods Specs Repo](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs) and clone it by
  using Source tree or command line or whatever you prefer.
- Once cloned open finder then `CMD + Shift + G` and type `~/` then
  create a folder named `.cocoapods` and paste the cloned repo. Finally
  the structure must looks like this:

[image]

- If you are unable to see the hidden files and folder then you need to
  run the following command and relaunch your finder.

`defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES`